# How to make a voip client with python - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, sip, voip

I have a working voip server and I want to make a voip client, I've tried with several python libraries and had no success with any because it was poorly explained and needed other libraries that I couldn't find

I was wondering if there is a way to make a "hacked" (manipulate, bind with python, terminate with python) voip client via line of code. I saw some client voip like lindphone, xlite, softphone and etc., but what I want is to be able to control it with python or any other language that I can call another number (internal / extension) by pressing a button on raspberry and making him call

Can someone help me? the idea is to use the gpio ports to make the call

Comment: Its probably not appropriate to ask a question about how to hack here. Also hacking means to use a system for something that it was otherwise created for. Thus if you want to find a way to use code with the intention of changing something it wouldnt be hacking, it would just be the program

Comment: If I had read it correctly, I would understand that I don't want to hack, but manipulate, bind with python, terminate with python

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. You would need something like Twilio API

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [sipcmd](http://sipcmd.sourceforge.net/) will fit the bill.

In a single command line you can make sipcmd establish a call to a destination. Then all you've got to do is call that via Python or whichever language when the GPIO pin is triggered.